# Successor to Remoting/WCF in .NET

Tags: .net, wcf, remoting

Few years ago remoting and WCF where commonly used to transfer data between apps in a local network.

Assuming these are pretty old technologies today, what is used instead to offer the same functionality?

Comment: For what kind of communication? The assumption isn't entirely correct.  WCF is the successor to Remoting. There is no successor to WCF for SOAP, Sockets. You can always use TcpClient, UdpClient, or the socket classes. Web API is used for HTTP REST services.

Comment: As for remoting, it was replaced by WCF in 2008

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So WCF is still used? Communication like uploading data from one .NET app to another.

Comment: As I said, for *what*? `uploading data from one .NET app to another.` isn't a valid term. If you want to pass data from one application to another you can even use the clipboard. In UWP applications you can use contracts to share data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's already stated in the post that purpose is LAN communication. Clipboard is off-topic.